How to fullscreen a 3rd-party application by its hwnd?
I'm looking to fullscreen 3rd-party windows in a (hopefully) reliable and consistent way for a window manager project. The goal is to have the fullscreen window cover the taskbar completely.
My current approach is to set the window's position and dimensions to match the current monitor. This works well for some windows, but for others, the taskbar ends up covering the bottom part of the window (see vid). Implementation:
use windows::Win32::{
  Foundation::HWND,
  Graphics::Gdi::{
    GetMonitorInfoW, MonitorFromWindow, MONITORINFOEXW,
    MONITOR_DEFAULTTONEAREST,
  },
  UI::WindowsAndMessaging::{
    SetWindowPos, HWND_NOTOPMOST, SWP_FRAMECHANGED, SWP_NOACTIVATE,
    SWP_NOCOPYBITS, SWP_NOSENDCHANGING,
  },
};

pub fn set_fullscreen(window_handle: isize) -> anyhow::Result<()> {
  let monitor_handle = unsafe {
    MonitorFromWindow(HWND(window_handle), MONITOR_DEFAULTTONEAREST)
  };

  let mut monitor = MONITORINFOEXW::default();
  monitor.monitorInfo.cbSize =
    std::mem::size_of::<MONITORINFOEXW>() as u32;

  unsafe {
    GetMonitorInfoW(monitor_handle, &mut monitor as *mut _ as _)
  }
  .ok()?;

  let monitor_rect = monitor.monitorInfo.rcMonitor;

  unsafe {
    SetWindowPos(
      HWND(window_handle),
      HWND_NOTOPMOST,
      monitor_rect.left,
      monitor_rect.top,
      monitor_rect.right - monitor_rect.left,
      monitor_rect.top - monitor_rect.bottom,
      SWP_FRAMECHANGED
        | SWP_NOACTIVATE
        | SWP_NOCOPYBITS
        | SWP_NOSENDCHANGING,
    )
  }?;

  Ok(())
}

I've tried a couple other approaches based on Raymond Chen's post on implementing fullscreen:

Removing the WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW style: This does make the windows cover the taskbar, but it's an intrusive change and sometimes causes the window to bug out.
Setting the z-order to HWND_TOPMOST: This also works to cover the taskbar, but forcing the window to be always on top isn't ideal.

Interestingly, some windows (like Spotify and Visual Studio) can successfully overlap the taskbar despite having the WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW style. Here's a comparison of window styles for various apps in normal and fullscreen modes:

VS Code (normal) - Fullscreen with above implementation covers taskbar ✅

styles: MaximizeBox | Group | SizeBox | Caption | ClipSiblings | Visible
styles ex: WindowEdge


VS Code (built-in f11 fullscreen)

styles: MaximizeBox | Group | ClipSiblings | Visible
styles ex: Left


Chrome (normal) - Fullscreen with above implementation does not cover taskbar ❌

styles: OverlappedWindow | ClipChildren | ClipSiblings | Visible
styles ex: WindowEdge


Chrome (built-in f11 fullscreen)

styles: MaximizeBox | Group | SysMenu | ClipChildren | ClipSiblings | Visible
styles ex: Left


Obsidian (normal) - Fullscreen with above implementation covers taskbar ✅

styles: MaximizeBox | Group | SizeBox | Caption | ClipSiblings | Visible
styles ex: WindowEdge


Obsidian (built-in f11 fullscreen)

styles: MaximizeBox | Group | ClipSiblings | Visible
styles ex: Left


Spotify (normal) - Fullscreen with above implementation covers taskbar ✅

styles: OverlappedWindow | ClipChildren | ClipSiblings | Visible
styles ex: WindowEdge


File explorer (normal) - Fullscreen with above implementation does not cover taskbar ❌

styles: OverlappedWindow | ClipSiblings | Visible
styles ex: WindowEdge


File explorer (built-in f11 fullscreen)

styles: Group | SysMenu | ClipSiblings | Visible
styles ex: Left


Visual Studio (normal) - Fullscreen with above implementation covers taskbar ✅

styles: OverlappedWindow | ClipChildren | ClipSiblings | Visible
styles ex: WindowEdge | AppWindow


Visual Studio (built-in f11 fullscreen) - interestingly, no change

styles: OverlappedWindow | ClipChildren | ClipSiblings | Visible
styles ex: WindowEdge | AppWindow



Since some apps can properly fullscreen with WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, I'm wondering if there's a way to achieve this behavior consistently across all windows.
What is the most reliable and consistent way to fullscreen a window so that it covers the taskbar completely?

You cannot do that. The ability to occlude the Task Bar has to be requested by the application itself (by setting uiAccess='true' in its manifest). You cannot force this behavior onto a window owned by a different process. That said, the solution to replacing the Shell is to write a Shell Replacement. I don't know whether this is officially supported.

@IInspectable After testing, I'm not seeing a difference based on the uiAccess setting. For example, I'm using the above snippet to fullscreen Spotify, which has uiAccess="false" in its manifest, and it still covers the taskbar.

Is Spotify an Electron app (which would explain identical behavior to VS Code)? I'm sure there are other means for a program to render in front of the Taskbar; fullscreen DirectX applications, for example, do not have to fight the Taskbar. Still, I'm not aware of a way to force any given window owned by any given thread on top of the Taskbar from the outside.

Spotify is an electron app, and it also has a custom title bar like VSCode. There’s a VSCode setting for using the native title bar instead of the custom one, which when enabled, causes it to no longer cover the taskbar when fullscreened. So it has something to do with the window frame in that case

HWND_TOPMOST is necessary. I've already tested it with WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW. Using GetDeviceCaps to obtain the height and width of of the physical screen in SetWindowPos can make it

@Torrecto-MSFT HWND_TOPMOST only seems to be necessary when the window doesn't have WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW. And even then, there are windows that seem to be able to be able to bypass this, like Spotify and VSCode, which have WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW and are able to cover the taskbar with the SetWindowPos call. Would you happen to know how these apps are able to do this? Could the same be done even with 3rd-party windows?

@L.Berger Topmost with WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW also can make it in win32 window. I cannot tell you about 3rd-party windows. They maybe created by other frame like uwp.
